# No of controls limit 200 exceeded when adding a connection to a webpart in the same page in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a view which has 4 webparts added to it. 
I am creating a connection from one field (say Id) to Id field of the other web parts. But the moment I added a connection to one of the web parts which has around 90 controls the page is giving me the error: "No of controls limit 200". 
When I remove that connection, the page is coming properly.

Can anyone identify the problem with this kind of problem and suggest something that is needful?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this entry in the web.config

```
<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="true" DirectFileDependencies="20" TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="false">
```